# Why can't quantum mechanics and general relativity be unified?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity

Excuse me for my little knowledge in physics, but it seems very bizarre for two theories, relativity and quantum mechanics (which describe phenomena very accurately in their regions) to be unable to be unified into a single model of the universe. Aren't they describe the same universe but different aspects of it. Why can't this be done?

Comment: We encourage users to [do a basic search of the site to see if their question has been asked before](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=quantum%20mechanics%20relativity%20is%3aquestion)

Comment: @JohnRennie How is my question a duplicate of the question mentioned above.